# Testing integer error in while loop

Tags: python-2.7

I have ran into some problems while trying to combine while loop and ValueError. 
Initially I wanted my program to add numbers together. When the sum of numbers has exceeded X, I would like my program to continue to else statement. At first I didn't focus on the fact that input could also be (for example) string.

```
number = 1

while number < 10:
    add = int(raw_input("Enter a number to add: "))
    number += add
    print number
else:
    print "Number is greater than 10"
```

I tried combining the first code with try/except and ValueError to accept integers as the only inputs. Second code will not continue to else statement when sum of numbers exceeds X. Could someone please explain why this is not working?

```
number = 1

while number < 10:
    while True:
        try:
            add = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
            number += add
            print number
        except ValueError:
            print "Please enter a number"
else:
    print "Number is greater than 10"
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an extra `while True:` loop resulting in an infinte loop.

Remove it and your code will work fine.

Another example where `while(condition)` (with condition not `True`) leads to mistakes: you have to ensure that the loop will be entered once, sometimes by initalizing your condition artificially. I would write that instead

```
    number = 1

    while True:
        try:
            add = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
            number += add
            print number
            if number>10:
               break
        except ValueError:
            print "Please enter a number"

    print "Number is greater than 10"
```